# Graphic Chart In C#

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net

I am trying to make Graphic Chart in C#. But I have got an error info like this

> ```
> Error System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid du to the current state of the object.
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
> at Oracle.DataAcess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader()
> at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form3.btnLOAD_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in ....
> ```

I have tried harder to solve this problem, but I did not find the way to rectify my coding program. Does anyone here could help me to rectify this problem please?
Thank you.
Here's my code

```
try
        {
            con.Open();
            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "SELECT * FROM TMCI_QC_LINE";
            command.CommandText = query;

            OracleDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                chart1.Series["QTY_NG"].Points.AddXY(Convert.ToInt32(dr["ITM_CD"].ToString()), Convert.ToInt32(dr["QTY_NG"].ToString()));
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
```

Comment: Do you have enough permission to read from database?

Comment: Yes, I have permission to access the database

Comment: Code shown in the post makes no sense - please review the code and make sure it is [MCVE]. In particular `connection` is not defined anywhere in the sample. (Also there is absolutely nothing about graphics or chart in the body of the post - you may want to update title while [edit] post with better code)

Comment: You see that with `con.Open()` you open a connection that you don't use in the command, right?. You use the `connection` object instead of `con`.

Comment: In addition to the fault Markus points at: Why convert perfectly fine numbers to useless strings when you want to create a chart?!? Do not do this!!!